# SharePoint online files in a document set are inheriting the document set title

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, document-set

I have a few document sets and the title column is acting like a shared column even though it is not. It's making it so I can't have different titles for the files inside the document set.

Does anyone know why it's doing this or if there is a setting I can change to title is not shared?

Answer (score 0):

It's by design as per mt knowledge, I'm afraid no way to change this. Just add a new column to replace with it.